# Passing variable through FileOutputStream

Tags: java, fileoutputstream

So I came accross this code to save something to a .text file using FileOutputStream

```
try (PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("filename.txt"))) {
    out.print(text);
}
```

Is there any way I could pass a variable to the filname such as FileOutputStream(*filename*.text)?

Comment: Well you can concatenate the value of a variable with `.txt`, e.g. `new FileOutputStream(filename + ".txt")`. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @spacing Consider selecting an answer to the question if the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String fileName = "filename.text"; // Your need be, I might have used .txt

try (PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName))) {
    out.print(text);
} catch (FileNotFoundException fnf) {
    fnf.printStackTrace(); // your .text would take you here ;)
}
```

What you are using here is [FileOutputStream's constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.lang.String)) which accepts a string parameter. So you can certainly modify it according to your needs.

***Note*** - Remember to catch the exception as well

Answer (score 3):

No problem.  Just use a string variable in the constructor like this:

```
String myFile = "filename.txt";
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(myFile)));
out.print(text);
```

One important comment, you should use the constructor that specifies the character encoding of the stream.  Anytime you convert a string to an output stream you will be encoding characters to bytes, and some character encoding will be used.  If you don't specify explicitly the encoding, then it will use `default` encoding wich might be different on different computers, and your code will run differently on different computers.

```
String myFile = "filename.txt";
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(myFile), "UTF-8"));
out.print(text);
```